# Public rewrites on private database

Tags: authentication, couchdb

I'm creating a *single page* CouchApp, using `_attachments` to serve the JavaScript application directly from CouchDB. I've set up a vhost to `db/_design/ddoc/_rewrite` to achieve this.

The data in the database can only be viewed by certain users in the `_users` database, which is achieved by adding them as members to the `db/_security` document.

I would like the single page application, which has PouchDB packaged, to take control of fetching data, and performing authentication by means of [pouchdb-authentication](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication). Herein lies the problem: I cannot access the application before authenticating.

That leads me to my question; Is there a way to expose the `_attachments` in a design document to unauthenticated users, *without* granting everybody access to the rest of the database? Currently I'm weighing toward storing my app in a separate database without any members, but I would prefer to use a single database and work it out with the permission system in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. Some things you can try are:

- Create the authentication app in a separate database that's public and empty, then redirect to your app from there (you have to be in the same domain).
- Create the authentication app outside of CouchDB and use a proxy to serve everything from the same domain.
- **THIS IS VERY UNSAFE AND SUBOPTIMAL** but for testing purposes you can enable Basic Auth in the application, which will give you a way to authenticate via the browser before you are denied access to the database.